# Join three tables mysql

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-tables

I have three tables of vendor details, services and venues. All has a common field as vendor id.

I want to show the services and venues related to the vendor.

I tried some joins but not getting the result.

one of them I tried is :

```
SELECT services.serviceId as Id, 
services.service_name as service_name,
services.entry_by as entry_by,
services.servicetypeId as servicetypeId, 
services.latitude as latitude,
services.longitude as longitude, 
services.active as active, 

vendorDetails.username, 
vendorDetails.emailId, 
vendorDetails.vendorAddress,
vendorDetails.vendorName,
vendorDetails.mobileno, 

venues.venueId as Id, 
venues.venue_name as venue_name, 
venues.entry_by as entry_by, 
venues.venuetypeId as venuetypeId, 
venues.latitude as latitude,
venues.longitude as longitude,
venues.active as active 

FROM `vendorDetails` v

inner join `venues` venue on v.vendorId = venues.venueId
inner join `services` s on v.vendorId  = s.vendorId
```

but it shows the error for services.serviceId as a unknown column. I checked the column does exist in services table.

How can I get this? Thank you..

Comment: Try using alias you defined for table names as below:

`SELECT s.serviceId as Id`  instead of `SELECT services.serviceId`

likewise...

Answer (score 0):

Actually you were using table alias as `v` `s` `venue` for the tables `vendorDetails` `services` `venues` respectively. Therefore the corresponding tablename were replaced by their alias for this particular query. Hence the original table name become unknown. And in `inner join`venues`venue on v.vendorId = venues.venueId` you are comparing `vendorId` with `venueId` which will return empty result set. Please try below query

```
SELECT 
    s.serviceId as Id, 
    s.service_name as service_name,
    s.entry_by as entry_by,
    s.servicetypeId as servicetypeId, 
    s.latitude as latitude,
    s.longitude as longitude, 
    s.active as active, 

    v.username, 
    v.emailId, 
    v.vendorAddress,
    v.vendorName,
    v.mobileno, 

    venue.venueId as Id, 
    venue.venue_name as venue_name, 
    venue.entry_by as entry_by, 
    venue.venuetypeId as venuetypeId, 
    venue.latitude as latitude,
    venue.longitude as longitude,
    venue.active as active 

FROM 
    `vendorDetails` v

Inner Join
    `venues` venue on v.vendorId = venue.vendorId 
Inner Join 
    `services` s on v.vendorId  = s.vendorId
```

Comment: I tried this, but it returns empty result though vendorId 32 has services as well as venues. @jonju

Comment: try again. Actually vendorId was comparing with venueId. Updated

Comment: it returns multiple records. @jonju

Comment: You must be having multiple records with same venderId in services & venues table